# Use NHibernate CreateSQLQuery Method for add output parameter

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to connect with sql server using NHibernate from MVC .NET application.

Here's what I am trying to do.

```
var result = nhSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec SearchWithPaging :SearchCriteria, :CurrentPage, :PageSize")
            .SetParameter("SearchCriteria", searchCriteria)
            .SetParameter("CurrentPage", currentPage)
            .SetParameter("PageSize", pageSize)
            .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(List<ListDto>)))
            .UniqueResult<List<ListDto>>();
```

Now I am able to get the data successfully. The problem is that I want proc to send me some output values as well. So I have increased the output parameters in my proc. But don't know how to do that here in CreateSQLQuery Method.

I have already googled it, but they have implemented it using SqlCommand and all that, including SqlDataReader. I don't wanna do that.

Comment: Every other StackOverflow Q&A about this says it's not possible without dropping into ADO.NET. I don't think that answer has changed, unfortunately.

Comment: To call stored procedures with OUT parameters i have to fallback to the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code. You can use http://www.gitshah.com/2011/09/calling-stored-procedure-with-out.html for more details

```
   public void ShouldEncryptTheValue()
{
   //Getting the instance of session factory using,
   //the NHibernateSessionHelper custom class.  
   //This step could be different in your case.
   //May be the session factory gets injected in some way.
   ISessionFactory sessionFactory = NHibernateSessionHelper.GetSessionFactory();

    //Step - 1 - Opening a NHibernate session using the session factory.
    var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    //Step - 2 - Starting the NHibernate transaction.
    session.BeginTransaction();

    //Step - 3 - Creating an instance of SqlCommand
    IDbCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    //Step - 4 - Setting the connection property of the command instance 
    //with NHibernate session's Connection property.
    command.Connection = session.Connection;

    //Step - 5 - Setting the CommandType property 
    //as CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Step - 6 - Setting the CommandText to the name 
    //of the stored procedure to invoke.
    command.CommandText = "encrypt";

    //Step - 7 - Set input parameter, 
    //in our case its "@stringToEncrypt" with the value to encrypt, 
    //in our case "Hello World"
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stringToEncrypt", "Hello World"));

    //Step - 8 - Set output parameter, in our case "encryptedValue".  
    //Notice that we are specifying the parameter type as second argument 
    //and its size as the third argument to the constructor.  
    //The Direction property is initialized in the initialization block 
    //with ParameterDirection.Output.
    SqlParameter outputParameter = 
        new SqlParameter("@encryptedValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
                       {
                           Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                       };
    command.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

    //Step - 9 - Enlisting the command with the NHibernate transaction.
    session.Transaction.Enlist(command);

    //Step - 10 - Executing the stored procedure.
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Step - 11 - Getting the value set by the stored procedure 
    //in the output parameter.
    var encryptedValue = 
        ((SqlParameter)command.Parameters["@encryptedValue"]).Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(encryptedValue);

    //Step - 12 - Cleanup.  Committing the NHibernate Transaction 
    //and closing the NHibernate session.
    session.Transaction.Commit();
    session.Close();
}
```